# JavaScript encryption (or obfuscation) of client-side data structures

Tags: javascript, user-interface, javascript-framework, saas

Is there a way to 'hide' structure and content of javascript objects?

I have fairly extensive JavaScript objects on my client side holding information about the users UI (and other things). It holds a lot of information about the resources that the user will be operating on. As it is, someone with Firebug can just open the console and see the structure of all that data. I'm not crazy about that for security reasons.

Are there any ways I can protect this data?

Thanks,

Comment: The only way to *properly* protect this kind of  data is not to have it client-side.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot protect that data.  Anything that can be seen and used by the browser can also be seen and used by a person inspecting what the browser has.

You really need to think about why is this a problem for you?  If you're concerned about a man-in-the-middle snoop who might intercept that data, then you should run your connections over https.

If you're concerned about the end-user themselves seeing this data, I'd ask why are you concerned about that?  It's the user's own state.  There should be no secrets in there.

If you're concerned that the user might manipulate things to do things on your server that they shouldn't be allowed to do, then you need to implement protection on your server for things the user shouldn't be allowed to do.  Clients cannot implement such protection because clients are, by definition, not secure in this regard.

If there is actually secure data on the client that the end-user themselves shouldn't have access to, then you need to rethink how your app works and keep that data only on the server.  The client should only have data that is absolutely required to be on the client.  It's possible to implement a UI with very little actual data in the client except specific fields that are being edited if you generate most of the UI server-side.

So ... in summary.  Don't put data in the client that the end-user shouldn't have access to.  Rethink how your app works if that's a problem.  If the end-user can have access to it, then don't work.  If nobody else should have access to it, then run your pages over https.

As for obfuscation, it's barely worth any effort.  Obfuscation does not provide any true security as it can always be defeated.  At best, it provides a level of annoyance to someone trying to look at your code.  A determined hacker will be able to get through the obfuscation by just spending a little more time on it and running it through some tools.  Certainly there is no harm in minifying your javascript code as that makes it smaller and makes it less readable by humans, but do not count it as any form of real security.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

However, you have some options:

1. You can obfuscate your javascript -- this will help slightly as it makes it harder to read and understand your code. There are plenty of good obfuscators out there. I advice against this!
2. You can minify your javascript -- this might look like an obfuscation method, but is not. It can easily be reverted back to readable javascript and is mainly intended for limiting bandwidth. I encourage this, but advice against it for this reason!
3. You can try to put as much of your sensitive data and code on your server. This might make sense, or it might not.
4. You can encrypt your data and decrypt it on-the-fly via your own javascript decryption library. Not a good idea, as it is fairly easy to by-pass this security and it is resource intensive. However it will slightly discourage "theft" of your data. **I strongly advice against this!**
5. If you can accept to only target Google Chrome (for now) or Chromium, you can implement your code and data in Native Client, which basically is compiled C code running in a sandbox in your browser (Chromium/Chrome). The only way to get access to your code is decompilation. If you are really paranoid over data theft, you can obfuscate your C code before compiling, to try to kill debuggers from snatching your data, and possibly fetch all your data over SSL from your server in real time rather than having it in your binary.

Though, remember, even with option 5 there are ways to claim your data, though it will be very few who both have the will, time and know-how to get it.

And also remember, if you are looking for a way to conceal sensitive data on the web, it is highly likely you have thought out your solution wrongly. Never ever put sensitive data on the client or use client side verification as your only verification. Perhaps the web is not the platform you are looking for? Perhaps you're looking for a distributed solution?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a security concern, don't send it to the client.  Even if you obfuscate it, you're not making it more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation can only get you so far, because the nature of Javascript is that it is downloaded to the user's system so that their browser (and user) can read it. Making something harder to read is not hiding it completely. You cannot encrypt it without giving your users some way to decrypt it, thus defeating the purpose. What you're looking for is a server-side language that's compiled before the user sees it, such as PHP, Python, Java, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. You can obfuscate, pack and do all kinds of stuff to make the source code harder to read. Hell, you can even give your objects really weird and indescript properties. But that's it really, you only make it harder to read. The data is there, and a determined attacker can find out what he wants if sensitive data is sent to the client.

So don't store sensitive data client side. Anyway, what's so horribly secret about UI state? If a user wants to break his state, let him?

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to try to obfuscate the javascript logic. 
But you can minify it (i.e. uglifying it). at least you would make it more difficult to read. 
If you are concerned about the security of your client side code, then there is no way but to use server side code. Perhaps making more code available through services and then calling your services through $.ajax or someting similar.